Will fine-tuning a LLM on general, domain-specific knowledge improve its performance on specific tasks?
I am fine tuning ChatGPT 4o-mini using instruction finetuning to extract details of a customer's complaints about specific products (scientific instruments) that my company markets.
I provide the following prompt and a transcript of a conversation (as input_text) like so:
COMPLAINT
Identify the following from the input text: customer's complaint.

Input text: [input_text]

This only works about approximately 70% of the time as the model seems to pick up random sentences, not necessarily pertaining to a product. It might even pick up sentences that refer to other products that the company does not market.
Would finetuning the model with product details, general physics and information regarding what is measured improve the model? Like so:
1. Orbitrap Astral Mass Spectrometer: The Orbitrap Astral Mass Spectrometer combines three mass analyzers: a quadrupole mass analyzer for high selectivity and high ion transmission...

2. Orbitrap Tribrid mass spectrometer: The architecture inside of an Orbitrap Tribrid mass spectrometer enables a broad range of experimental applications from discovery to profiling and quantification, expediting scientific advancements while offering experimental flexibility, all on a single instrument... 

3. Science of mass spectrometry: ...

If it would improve the output, how would I word the instructions to finetune the model?
